# How to fit linear slope to a graph in a specified range of x values?

Tags: python, graph

For example, here is a data set:

```
X: 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10 

Y: 20, 21, 22, 26, 32, 41, 39, 36, 29, 23
```

I think I'm supposed to be using the NumPy `polyfit` function, but not sure.
How can I, for example, get the linear fit between `x(3)` and `x(6)`?

Just calculating in my head, this should be something like: `rise/run = (41-22)/(6-3) = 6.3333333...`

I'm dealing with different data sets each time that I read in as `.txt` files, so I would really appreciate if someone showed me the general method to do this, which I could then apply to all future datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want a least square fit, which is what polyfit will give you.

To achieve that, you simply pass two lists to polyfit, the x values, the y values and you have to set the order of polynomial you want. So for your example, this would turn out to be

```
import numpy as np

x = [3, 6]
y = [22, 41]
coeffs = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

# get the y values of the resulting line
x = np.arange(1,11)
y_line = x * coeffs[0] + coeffs[1]
```

With regard to your further questions, you need to think about the output of polyfit.

The documentation for `numpy.polyfit` says

> The solution minimizes the squared error
>
> E = \sum_{j=0}^k |p(x_j) - y_j|^2
>
> in the equations:
>
> x[0]**n * p[0] + ... + x[0] * p[n-1] + p[n] = y[0]
>
> x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCoiS.png)**n * p[0] + ... + x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCoiS.png) * p[n-1] + p[n] = y[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCoiS.png)
>
> ...
>
> x[k]**n * p[0] + ... + x[k] * p[n-1] + p[n] = y[k]

We are using a very simplified case, because to get just a straight line, we have a polynomial of first order, that is, `n=1`.

That means in our case, the equation for `y` is simply `y[k] = x[k]*p[0]+p[1]`. Compare that to the general form of the line equation `y = k*x+d`. You will see that the slope of your line is simply `coeffs[0]`.

As for plotting, see the following example

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(1, 11)
y = [20, 21, 22, 26, 32, 41, 39, 36, 29, 23]

poly = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)

y_line = x * poly[0] + poly[1]

print poly[0]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, y_line)
plt.show()
```

which results in the output

```
$ python test.py 
1.21818181818
```

[image]

Comment: that makes sense, but how do i then plot the line (get it to appear on my graph) as well as display the slope of the line?

Comment: @nikhar It would have been somewhat beneficial to include that in your question, no? I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @nikhar Feel free to accept my answer if this satisfies your question.

Comment: "*you will see that the slope of your line is simply coeffs[1]*" -- do you mean `coeffs[0]`?

Comment: @PaulH You are correct, thanks. I have edited my mistake.